# Using predefined function with parameters as completion block in swift

Tags: ios, swift, closures

EDIT: I thought the issue was Swift syntax, but the problem was that I did not know that the UIViewController.presentViewController specifies a signature for the completion handler that takes no input parameters.

I have to provide a completion handler to presentViewController. The completion handler I want to provide takes an input parameter. What is the syntax to handle this in swift?

If the handler did not take an input parameter it would look like this:

```
self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: myHandler)
```

But how would the above line look if myHandler was declared like this:

```
func myHandler(myParameter: AnyObject){
    ...
}
```

Comment: dispatch_block_t maybe? https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/dispatch_block_t

Comment: are you trying to pass in a function that expects one parameter as a completion block which does not provide a parameter?

Comment: That does not look like it relates to the question, I'll try to edit to make it more clear what I am asking about

Comment: Well the self.presentViewController uses `(() -> Void) ` as its completion handler if that is what you want. If you want it to return a value you would use something like `(() -> Int)`

Comment: Ok, I'm not looking to return a value, but I guess the same answer goes for input values. The signature of the expected completion handler takes no inputs, is that correct?

Comment: What do you want the completion handler to do? Typically you would have at least one input and then the completion result would be a `Bool` or some sort of error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That does not work unfortunately. You cannot just pass in a function that has an invalid type for the completion block. It expects a closure without any parameters and with no return type / `void`. You are providing a function that expects a `AnyObject` and returns nothing / `void`. Therefore there is a mismatch between the expected `(() -> Void)` and the provided `((AnyObject) -> Void)`

How would the program know what to pass in to `myHandler` as `myParameter`?

The only way I can think of to achieve this is to write a wrapper for the custom completion handler:

```
self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion:{self.myHandler("")})
```

That way you provide a completion block that calls the `myHandler` but actually provides a value for `myParameter`.

Comment: You're right, taking a look at the declaration of UIViewController.presentViewController clearly shows why it can't be done. Another question is what the syntax would be **if** presentViewController expected a completion handler with an input parameter..

Comment: @Videre THEN it would be the same like if it would not expect one, then you would just write `self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion:myHandler)` - iif `myHandler` expects a parameter of the same type and has a matching return type.

Answer (score 1):

I should have looked at the [declaration of presentViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController:animated:completion:) before asking the question, but I am inexperienced with closures and thought any closure could be passed. It turns out that the issue is that presentViewController takes a very specific closure of the form

```
(() -> Void)?
```

The full signature is here:

```
func presentViewController(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController,
              animated flag: Bool,
            completion completion: (() -> Void)?)
```

So the answer is that presentViewController cannot take a completion handler that itself takes another parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking to do the following:

```
function myHandler(myParameter: (() -> Void)) {
//code here
}
```

Of course `-> Void` would change depending on if you want the function